# SVN Missing in solution explorer of visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, tortoisesvn

I have setup svn and its working fine but i am unable to find it from my solution explorer of visual studio but i can easily commit and update my solution from project folder in my local drive.
any one have better idea what i am missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TortoiseSVN does not integrate with Visual Studio by default (See [this article](http://tortoisesvn.net/visualstudio.html) on how to enable integration). You should consider using a Visual Studio PlugIn like [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) or [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are missing the fact that Visual Studio does not have native Apache Subversion support. If you already use TortoiseSVN you may want to consider [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/) extension, and I strongly advise you to give it a shot. The other option is [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) plugin.